# jersey and angularjs download zip file from server

Tags: java, angularjs, jersey

I am trying to download a zip file from my web api controller. It is returning the file but I am getting a message the zipfile is invalid when i try to open. And in browser file looks something like this:

PKj&�JCDA.xsl�=ks�8���W�TuwNmd�-ңxV��Ļ~��xg?� �X�H-N�W�߯J�H�t�$���$�h��B���m����k��B��,۝�k}�{��[(�ka�sɻ�#   Z���h�v>:$���q  C�-�|���d��5������
۵M�=3Z7D�
N����<�'��ׯ_���Ǟ?�H� v����s��mۥ8���z׊|�d�t�P��A�ׁ}�����C֙ld�S��a䓎i���y<��V��/�|������1�}�:�����|�ߵ�cQ;��X

```
File tempFileXml = File.createTempFile("generated-" + System.currentTimeMillis(), ".xml");
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(tempFileXml, ccdaXml);
File fileZip = new File(tempFileXml.getAbsolutePath() + ".zip");
if (!fileZip.exists()) {
  fileZip.createNewFile();
}
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileZip));
ZipEntry xsl = new ZipEntry("CDA.xsl");
zos.putNextEntry(xsl);
InputStream xmlIs = new FileInputStream(tempFileXml);
byte[] xslBytes = new byte[1024];
int xslLength;
while ((xslLength = xmlIs.read(xslBytes)) >= 0) {
  zos.write(xslBytes, 0, xslLength);
}
zos.closeEntry();
xmlIs.close();
zos.close();
ResponseBuilder rBuild = Response.ok(fileZip, "application/zip").header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; " + fileZip.getName())
        .type("application/zip");
return rBuild.build();
```

}

and on client side:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jamu1.png)
tried with application/zip too

Any ideas? In advance thanks for answers.

Comment: What browser is this?

Comment: chrome on linux

Comment: I tried in firefox. same